# AngularJS - Qual a melhor prática ao fazer upload de imagens?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, upload, imagem, callback

Implementei esta solução para fazer o upload das imagens:

```
MaquinaResource.save($scope.maquina, function (data, responseHeaders) {
   var formDataImage = new FormData();

   for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.images.length; i++) {
       formDataImage.append('file', $scope.images[i].file);
   }

   if($scope.images.length > 0) {
      $http.post('rest/maquina/'+data.id+'/upload/imagem',    formDataImage, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
   }
}
```

Particularmente não gostei dessa solução, mas existem pontos positivos nela. Se uma imagem falhar, falham todas (o que é o esperado). Porém estou tendo problemas com imagens mais pesadas. Qual a melhor prática ao fazer o upload dessas imagens? Pensei em upar uma por vez, invocando sempre a próxima no callback da atual, mas isso me traria um problema transacional (se uma imagem falhar as anteriores já estarão salvas). Qual a melhor solução nesses casos?

Answer (score 4):

A resposta irá depender dos requisitos da sua aplicação. O que você implementou foi um processo **síncrono e linear**. Você pode implementar:

- Um processo de upload em **paralelo e assíncrono**, onde todos os arquivos são enviados ao mesmo tempo. Se necessário, implemente um token para indicar a participação deste arquivo em um grupo.
  **Vantagens**: Simples implementação, se um arquivo falhar isso não significa que seu processo como um todo será comprometido.
  **Desvantagens**: A concorrência de todos os processos de upload simultâneos causará um *delay* para que até mesmo o menor arquivo seja recebido pelo servidor.
- Uma **fila** com **buffer** e **limitação de envios em paralelo**.
  **Vantagens**: Melhor uso de banda, melhor experiência de usuário.
  **Desvantagens**: Complexidade de implementação.

Seu código pode ser facilmente refatorado para se aplicar ao primeiro tipo:

```
MaquinaResource.save($scope.maquina, function (data, responseHeaders) {
   var formDataImage = new FormData();

   for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.images.length; i++) {
      $http.post('rest/maquina/'+data.id+'/upload/imagem', {file: $scope.images[i].file}, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
   }
}
```